# Angular Nested array filtering whole object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have the following code on the controller.js and gallery.html

```js
 .controller ('VideoGalleryController', ['$scope', 'videogalleryFactory', function($scope, videogalleryFactory){    
     //Values of genre searchbox
  $scope.genreOptions = [
         'Action',
         'Adventure',
         'Comedy',
         'Crime',
         'Drama',
         'Historical',
         'Horror',
         'Mistery',
         'Musical',
         'Romance',
         'Science Fiction',
         'Thriller',
         'Western'
         ];
  
  //Get dishes from db_movies.json
  videogalleryFactory.getMovies().query(
                function(response) {
                    $scope.movies = response;
                    //Displays nested genres
                    angular.forEach($scope.movies, function(item){
                     console.log(item.genre);
                    })
                },
                function(response) {
                    $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                });     
 }])
```

```html
 <div class="row row-content-cards">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
   <!-- Title filter --> 
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label label-title" for="search">Search movie:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search movie" ng-model="moviesfilter.title">
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Genre filter -->
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="genre" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Search genre</label>                           
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <select class="form-control"
       multiple 
       chosen    
       id="genre"
       name="genre"        
       data-placeholder="Search genres"
       no-results-text="'Could not find that genre'"
       ng-model="???" 
       ng-options="s for s in genreOptions">
       <option value=""></option>
     </select>    
    </div>   
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
   
 <div class="container-fluid cards-row">
  <div calss="hover-effect">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:moviesfilter as filtText">
    <div class="hover-div">
        <div class="thumbnail">
           <img ng-src={{movie.cover}} alt="{{movie.alt}}" >
           <div class="caption">
             <h3>{{movie.title}}</h3>
             <span class="badge-space badge" ng-repeat="genre in movie.genre | filter:genre"><strong>{{genre}} </strong></span>
             <div class="titlewraptext">
              {{movie.plot}}
             </div>
             <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Details</a></p>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
 <p ng-if="filtText.length === 0">
       <strong>No results found...</strong>
    <p>
</div>
```

I want on the [Filter by genre screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYyUb.png) once a value is selected the whole movie to be filtered. In this example only "La momia" and "Gladiator" should be displayed.

The json file structure is the following one:

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "title": "La momia",
      "releasedate": "1998-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
      "length": 125,
      "genre": [
        "Adventure"
      ],
      "plot": "Durante una batalla en Egipto, el legionario Rick O'Connell y un compañero descubren las ruinas de Hamunaptra, la ciudad de los muertos. Algún tiempo después vuelven al mismo lugar con una egiptóloga y su hermano. Allí coinciden con un grupo de estadounidenses, deseosos de correr aventuras, que acabarán provocando la resurrección de la momia de un diabólico sacerdote egipcio que intenta desesperadamente recuperar a su amada.",
      "cast": "Brendan Fraser, Rachel Weisz, John Hannah, Arnold Vosloo, Jonathan Hyde, Oded Fehr, Kevin J. O'Connor, Stephen Dunham, Aharon Ipalé, Tuc Watkins, Omid Djalili, Erick Avari, Carl Chase, Corey Johnson, Bernard Fox, Patricia Velasquez, Ray Donn",
      "cover": "img/film_covers/lamomia.png",
      "downloaddate": "2000-02-04T23:00:00.000Z",
      "alt": "La momia",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "Los juegos del hambre",
      "releasedate": "2011-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
      "length": 143,
      "plot": "Lo que en el pasado fueron los Estados Unidos, ahora es una nación llamada Panem; un imponente Capitolio ejerce un control riguroso sobre los 12 distritos que lo rodean y que están aislados entre sí. Cada distrito se ve obligado a enviar anualmente un chico y una chica entre los doce y los dieciocho años para que participen en los Hunger Games, unos juegos que son transmitidos en directo por la televisión. Se trata de una lucha a muerte, en la que sólo puede haber un superviviente. Katniss Everdeen, una joven de dieciséis años, decide sustituir a su hermana en los juegos; pero para ella, que ya ha visto la muerte de cerca, la lucha por la supervivencia es su segunda naturaleza.",
      "cover": "img/film_covers/losjuegosdelhambre.jpg",
      "cast": "Jennifer Lawrence, Josh Hutcherson, Elizabeth Banks, Woody Harrelson, Donald Sutherland, Stanley Tucci, Liam Hemsworth, Toby Jones, Lenny Kravitz, Wes Bentley, Paula Malcomson, Isabelle Fuhrman, Sandra Ellis Lafferty, Paula Malcomson, Kimiko Gelman, Nelson Ascencio, Brooke Bundy, Amandla Stenberg, Dayo Okeniyi, Leven Rambin, Jack Quaid, Latarsha Rose, Alexander Ludwig, Jacqueline Emerson",
      "downloaddate": null,
      "alt": "Los juegos del hambre",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Drama",
        "Science Fiction"
      ],
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "title": "Gladiator",
      "releasedate": "2000-04-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "length": 155,
      "plot": "En el año 180, el Imperio Romano domina todo el mundo conocido. Tras una gran victoria sobre los bárbaros del norte, el anciano emperador Marco Aurelio (Richard Harris) decide transferir el poder a Máximo (Russell Crowe), bravo general de sus ejércitos y hombre de inquebrantable lealtad al imperio. Pero su hijo Cómodo (Joaquin Phoenix), que aspiraba al trono, no lo acepta y trata de asesinar a Máximo.",
      "cover": "img/film_covers/gladiator.jpg",
      "cast": "Russell Crowe, Joaquin Phoenix, Connie Nielsen, Oliver Reed, Richard Harris, Ralf Moeller, Derek Jacobi, Djimon Hounsou, David Schofield, John Shrapnel, Spencer Treat Clark, Tomas Arana, David Hemmings, Tommy Flanagan, Sven-Ole Thorsen, Tony Curran, Giorgio Cantarini, Omid Djalili, Giannina Facio, Michael Sheen",
      "downloaddate": null,
      "alt": "Gladiator",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "Historical"
      ],
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "series": []
}
```

Comment: All that angular.forEach is going to do is iterate all your objects and display genre. Curious, what are you a) using angular.foreach for instead of just Array.forEach and b) why aren't you using Array.filter instead of just iterating it?

Comment: That angular.forEach is just for debugging purposes. It does nothing but displaying in console the genres of each movie

Comment: Right, but from your question, you're trying to filter? It's early and I haven't had all my coffee, but I don't see any filtering logic.

Comment: It is quite difficult to explain. The select box on the "gallery.html" displays a list with different genres. What I want is, once one genre is selected, the whole card (movie) with that genre to be filtered and displayed. In the screenshot only 2 cards should be displayed.

Nothing has been developed because all my tries ended with no success, so I don´t know how to do it.

Comment: I will post a sample of how to filter your JSON, based on a genre, to return an array with only the items you want. You can then use that array to bind to an ng loop or however you're displaying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do it.

```
let target_genre = 'Adventure'; // what your user selected
let movies = obj.movies; // your movies array from your JSON

// Find out if a movie's genres contains the target genre
// If so, return it to the new array.
let movies_filtered = movies.filter ( x => { 
  return x.genre.indexOf ( target_genre ) >= 0 } );

console.log ( movies_filtered ); // two movies
```

Edit: Since the actual use was an array of genres, here you can test for "any genre matches", or "all genres match". Note that the assumption now is that if it can be an array of genres, it should always be an array of genres, even if it's one long, otherwise you'll have to write "if it's an array do it this way, if not do it that way," code. If it's always an array, even one long, you just always do it the "it's an array" way.

```
let target_genres = [ 'Adventure', 'Drama', 'Historical' ];
let movies = obj.movies; // your movies array

// Returns if any genre matches
let movies_filtered = movies.filter ( x => { 
  return target_genres.filter ( y => {
    return x.genre.indexOf ( y ) >= 0;
  }).length; // if length is 0, that's "false", anything else is "true".
});

// Returns if all genres match
let movies_filtered = movies.filter ( x => { 
  let originalLength = target_genres.length;
  return target_genres.filter ( y => {
    return x.genre.indexOf ( y ) >= 0;
  }).length === originalLength; // filtered array length must match original length
});
```

Comment: It worked!! It returns as you said the array with 2 movies!! Now I have to adapt it to my necessities! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah isn't it annoying how simple these sorts of algs look when you see the answer. The one thing I've learned about algs is, if you need more than a few lines of code to test a base case, you're probably heading in the wrong direction. However, map/filter/reduce(fold), and now with Sets, union/diff/intersection, are pretty straightforward and most definitely required reading for any JS dev.

Comment: One small question, if I want to pass 2 parameters on the genre? Who would it work?

I have tried: target_genre = ['Adventure','Historical];

But it returns empty array

Comment: Yeah that won't work because target is supposed to be a string, not an array (you can't just swap things around like that). However, if you loop that array of target genres and run the above code in that loop, you could do it without changing the code. Otherwise, you would loop the target genres in the filter function, and if any of them are >= 0, you return it.

Comment: Updating answer with "any genre found, all genres found". Note that if it is possible that you will be submitting an array of genres, then you should always submit an array, even if it is an array of length = 1 (this way you don't have to write any code to say, "if it's not an array, do it this way, if it is, do it that way". It's just always an array, so you always do it that way).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution with es6 :)

```
const filteredMoviesByGenreType = (data, genreType) => {
   // access to object with key "movies" in data via spread operator and dot notation and filtering by genreType
   return [...data.movies]
     .filter(movie => movie["genre"]
     .includes(genreType));
 }
```

where data is your whole json data from server.

e.g output for only Drama's genres:

```
filteredMoviesByGenreType(data, "Drama");

[[object Object] {
  alt: "Los juegos del hambre",
  cast: "Jennifer Lawrence, Josh Hutcherson, Elizabeth Banks, Woody Harrelson, Donald Sutherland, Stanley Tucci, Liam Hemsworth, Toby Jones, Lenny Kravitz, Wes Bentley, Paula Malcomson, Isabelle Fuhrman, Sandra Ellis Lafferty, Paula Malcomson, Kimiko Gelman, Nelson Ascencio, Brooke Bundy, Amandla Stenberg, Dayo Okeniyi, Leven Rambin, Jack Quaid, Latarsha Rose, Alexander Ludwig, Jacqueline Emerson",
  cover: "img/film_covers/losjuegosdelhambre.jpg",
  downloaddate: null,
  genre: ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction"],
  id: 2,
  length: 143,
  plot: "Lo que en el pasado fueron los Estados Unidos, ahora es una nación llamada Panem; un imponente Capitolio ejerce un control riguroso sobre los 12 distritos que lo rodean y que están aislados entre sí. Cada distrito se ve obligado a enviar anualmente un chico y una chica entre los doce y los dieciocho años para que participen en los Hunger Games, unos juegos que son transmitidos en directo por la televisión. Se trata de una lucha a muerte, en la que sólo puede haber un superviviente. Katniss Everdeen, una joven de dieciséis años, decide sustituir a su hermana en los juegos; pero para ella, que ya ha visto la muerte de cerca, la lucha por la supervivencia es su segunda naturaleza.",
  releasedate: "2011-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
  title: "Los juegos del hambre"
}, [object Object] {
  alt: "Gladiator",
  cast: "Russell Crowe, Joaquin Phoenix, Connie Nielsen, Oliver Reed, Richard Harris, Ralf Moeller, Derek Jacobi, Djimon Hounsou, David Schofield, John Shrapnel, Spencer Treat Clark, Tomas Arana, David Hemmings, Tommy Flanagan, Sven-Ole Thorsen, Tony Curran, Giorgio Cantarini, Omid Djalili, Giannina Facio, Michael Sheen",
  cover: "img/film_covers/gladiator.jpg",
  downloaddate: null,
  genre: ["Action", "Adventure", "Drama", "Historical"],
  id: 3,
  length: 155,
  plot: "En el año 180, el Imperio Romano domina todo el mundo conocido. Tras una gran victoria sobre los bárbaros del norte, el anciano emperador Marco Aurelio (Richard Harris) decide transferir el poder a Máximo (Russell Crowe), bravo general de sus ejércitos y hombre de inquebrantable lealtad al imperio. Pero su hijo Cómodo (Joaquin Phoenix), que aspiraba al trono, no lo acepta y trata de asesinar a Máximo.",
  releasedate: "2000-04-30T22:00:00.000Z",
  title: "Gladiator"
}]
```